# unable not displaying warnings using scons with VC10 in windows XP

Tags: python, python-2.7, scons

Am using Scons with VC10. I found one problem while compiling my source code in windowsXP environment. Scons is not able to displaying warnings while compiling.

But the warnings are displayed in windows7 environment with the same code.

Is there any flags to enable scons to display warnings in windows Xp.

Comment: Can you try compiling "by hand" in Windows XP and see if the warnings are displayed. When I say "by hand" I mean copy/paste the compilation command and execute it in a command prompt without SCons. I doubt this is a problem with SCons as it doesnt filter the output returned by the compiler.

Comment: Hi Brady. I have tried by hand. i am getting the warning datails

Comment: With the same compilation options scons is able to produce the warnings in windows7 32 and 64bit machine.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the compiler is being invoked differently by hand than by SCons. Also, check to make sure you're not using any of the SCons command line options like "--warn=no-all", "--silent", or "--quiet".

Comment: No brady. i am not using any --warn --silent --quiet options. Does scons enabling them defaultly. i have seen one thing also like, if we compile a .C file using "cl", normally it should print the file name. But i am not getting the file name. i think scons is filtering all messages/text from the compiler and only redirecting the error to the output. Do we have any option to disable this.

Comment: None of those options are enabled by default. This is strange, SCons shouldnt be filtering anything. Try asking on the SCons user's mail list: Scons-users@scons.org

Comment: I would sugguest making a simple SConstruct and simple c or c++ file which just compiles one file and see if you still see the same behavior.  If you do, then either post it here, or send a description of your problem with the sample files to the scons-users@scons.org mailing list. (BTW. I'm the co-manager of the SCons project)